# How Do I use this "=IF(F2>E2, F2-E2, ("24:00:00"-E2)+F2)" in VB.net code?

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am trying to reduce the time taken to generate the reports for an application. We generate the reports in Excel. We found that some calculation are much faster in Excel using formula than programmatically doing it in VB.net

So basically I need to use the following formula(Time difference) in VB.net code. but it is giving me an error.

`=IF(F2>E2, F2-E2, ("24:00:00"-E2)+F2)`

What I tried

```
Dim f As String = "=if(RC[-1]>RC[-2], RC[-1]-RC[-2], (" & "24:00:00" & "-RC[-2])+RC[-1]"

wbXl.Sheets("time diff", 7).FormulaR1C1 = f

wbXl.Sheets("time diff").Cells(2, 7).FormulaR1C1 = """"=if(RC[-1]>RC[-2], RC[-1]-RC[-2], ("24:00:00" & "-RC[-2])+RC[-1]""""
```

and few other combination but nothing seems to be working.

Any pointers or help would be really helpful.

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: I am getting Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: Thanks @pnuts , That worked, 

here is code again

Checks if the time A is greater that B and subtract accordingly  
    wbXl.Sheets("Unique Session").Cells(2, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]>RC[-2], RC[-1]-RC[-2],RC[-1]+1-RC[-2])"

Sets the format of the text to h:mm:ss 
    wbXl.Sheets("Unique Session").Range("G2:G" & lrow + 1).NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss;@"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do I start…

```
Dim f As String = "=if(RC[-1]>RC[-2], RC[-1]-RC[-2], (" & "24:00:00" & "-RC[-2])+RC[-1]"
```

That is not a valid syntax in Excel (you can’t assign the value at the time you Dim it… get .net if you want to do that!)

What is up with the “24:00:00” in quotes?  Why not just subtract 1?

And all the quotes… it should be:

```
Cells(2, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(RC[-1]>RC[-2], RC[-1]-RC[-2], (""24:00:00""-RC[-2])+RC[-1])"
```

Or better:

```
Cells(2, 7).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(RC[-1]>RC[-2], RC[-1]-RC[-2], (1-RC[-2])+RC[-1])"
```

I’m also assuming you're using RC notation because you're going to do dynamic entry.  Otherwise, just use the cell IDs (easier to maintain).   Re-reading, it’s in .net calling Excel (what I’m gathering).  Otherwise, I’d say the sheet syntax should be different.  (and most people prefer Range to Cell.  `Cell(2,7)` is harder to read than `Range("$G$2")`. )

And here’s how I’d write the formula:

```
=B8+(B8<A8)-A8
(or in RC: =RC[-1]+(RC[-1]<RC[-2])-RC[-2])
```

Removes some of the redundancy of the original:

```
=IF(B6>A6,B6-A6,("24:00:00"-A6)+B6)
```

Comment: Hello Robert, Thanks for that, I am using **.net**, 'Cells(2, 7).FormulaR1C1' just as an example that has been used, I used formula in excel it worked good put could not use this dynamically in .net for multiple sheet.  Also I still don't understand concept of subtracting 1. can you please explain.